# Music on all user accounts?

Tags: music, clementine

I downloaded all of my music onto my sudo account on my laptop (approx 100Gb of music) but I can only access the music on my sudo account now. It doesn't show up on my "guest" accounts (I assume lack of privileges).

Does anyone know a fix that would allow me to access music on all accounts on my laptop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get an external HD for your music. The other profiles wont look into your home folder for stuff as it's owned by sudo, and cannot be accessed.

If you cannot get another HD, then follow [these instructions](https://superuser.com/questions/280994/give-write-permissions-to-multiple-users-on-a-folder-in-ubuntu/%22%22) to give the other profiles access to your files.

Comment: I back up everything on external HD ;)Buuuut apparently im super noob when it comes to this; How would the                    /path/to/the/directory look if the folder were in home/music folder?

Comment: /home/user/music

Comment: and replace user with your username

Comment: **IT IS CASE SENSITIVE** @D

Comment: Yes, Success! Worked like a charm thanks for all the help

Comment: I would recommend using your Public-directory for that though. Or you could have a shared folder for all users, such as /home/shared.

Comment: If you liked my question, maybe make that approved answer a pretty green color for me? @Daedalus

Comment: Didnt even see that button there! Was just trying to vote it up lol